# Display combined rep total on Stack Exchange users reputation page

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stack-exchange

I think it would be useful to display the combined flair (or something similar) alongside the graph on the SE reputation tab.

As it stands (although the information is available on another page) it is difficult to do the maths. You can currently see the individual totals together by hovering over the graph, but the combined total is displayed nowhere on the page.

[image]

Comment: I agree, the only place I know of to see it (not abbreviated like 9.5K) is at area 51.

Comment: Area 51 doesn't show the total reputation you have across all the Stack Exchange sites; it shows just the combined reputation for the X sites where your reputation is higher.

Answer (score 11):

I hope this is implemented natively at some point, but until then I went ahead and wrote a userscript that adds the total/displayed reputation on the graph, in the following fashion:

[image: global reputation displayed on graph]

You can install and get more details about the script from [its listing on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2575/stack-exchange-reputation-graph-total-reputation-overlay).

Since originally writing the script, I've also modified it to [add an additional graph plot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142111/add-an-option-to-show-cumulative-score-on-the-reputation-graph/142245#142245) so you have the option of seeing how your network reputation has changed over time.

Answer (score 3):

Go to any commitment page on Area 51 and it shows a combined flair:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5425/operating-systems-development

So the code exists to create a flair with this information. All we need is to convince Stack Exchange to give us that flair on our Stack Exchange user page...

Comment: The reputation shown in Area 51 is not the sum of the reputation you have in all the Stack Exchange sites. With users with referred users, the reputation shown as "total rep" is the sum of the reputation of all the users.

Answer (score 1):

### Accumulated totals from all sites

I had the same question and there is now a solution - Chrome Only.

[Add an option to show cumulative score on the reputation graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142111/161218)