# SE Total Rep Count

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page, linked-accounts, combined-flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display combined rep total on Stack Exchange users reputation page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87774/display-combined-rep-total-on-stack-exchange-users-reputation-page)
>   [Why doesn't the network profile list total reputation and badges across the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136425/why-doesnt-the-network-profile-list-total-reputation-and-badges-across-the-netw)

Any chance of getting a total rep count across all SE sites for your account to show up on (at the very least) your official stack exchange user profile page?

Right now it only shows rep counts for each individual site.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87774/display-combined-rep-total-on-stack-exchange-users-reputation-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ['flair' image](https://stackexchange.com/users/240035/di-0xide?tab=flair) shows the total count, but it only includes sites with > 200 rep:

[image: Di-0xide flair]

I have a few more sites over 200:

[image: Martijn Pieters flair]

You can get a flair image *per stack exchange site* too, look for the 'flair' link on your profile, but that doesn't give you the total of course.

Flair images are cached for 24-36 hours.

Comment: Aha, there we go! That's what I needed to know!

Comment: It shows reputations in short form (i.e. `35K`). But How can we get it in full form (i.e. `35120`)

Comment: See [Display combined rep total on Stack Exchange users reputation page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87774) if you are currently committed to a Area51 proposal it'll show your total (in shortened form with a tooltip showing the precise total), or you can use the user script listed in one answer there.