# Could the User Page be expanded to show net reputation change per site?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, stackexchange.com

Like a lot of us who are <strike>addicted</strike> regular users of Stack Exchange, I tend to look at my [overall account page](https://stackexchange.com/users/45534/affable-geek?tab=accounts) a fair amount.  This is my home screen to see if there's been a lot of activity on any one of the numerous sites I care about.

But, in using that page as my starting point for the entire Stack Exchange network, I'm realizing that I'm carrying needless information in my head - in order to see what's been trending within my "portfolio," I have to know about where I was the last time I saw the page.  There's no reason for that.  It should be a trivial addition to the page to add a daily & weekly change for each site in my profile.  (It's available in the reputation leagues, so its just a matter of showing it on the page).

Personally, I'd have the two numbers appear in regular size font, one over top of the other, next to the total amount.  If there has been no change in the last day or week, just leave the area blank. This doesn't clutter the page up too much, but adds a lot of information.

Additionally, for other users, it is a good proxy of how active any other user has been recently.  By seeing what sites a user is more and less active on, I get a better sense of what is important to them.

So, could we add net reputation change to the main page?

And, while we are at it, my flair shows my overall reputation (albeit rounded).  [I'd love to see that total number on my page too.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87774/display-combined-rep-total-on-stack-exchange-users-reputation-page)

Comment: Related to the last point: [Display combined rep total on Stack Exchange users reputation page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87774)